# polars group by returning a value when filters does not match

Tags: python-polars

let's say I have this polars dataframe

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
   {
      "group_col": ["g1", "g1", "g2"],
      "b": [1, 2, 3],
      "c": [4, 5, 6]
   }
)
```

output

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ group_col ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ ---       ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str       ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ g1        ┆ 1   ┆ 4   │
│ g1        ┆ 2   ┆ 5   │
│ g2        ┆ 3   ┆ 6   │
└───────────┴─────┴─────┘
```

i need to do a group by like this:

```
df.group_by("group_col").agg(
    [
        pl.col("c").filter((pl.col("b") >= 1) & (pl.col('b').max() == pl.col('b'))).max().alias("gte"),
    ]
)
```

output:

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────┬─────┐
│ group_col ┆ gte │
│ ---       ┆ --- │
│ str       ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪═════╡
│ g1        ┆ 5   │
│ g2        ┆ 6   │
└───────────┴─────┘
```

in this case, why the value in column gte in the group g1 is not null? given the  `& (pl.col('b').max() == pl.col('b'))` filter?

Comment: I need to get the max value from "c" where "b" is equal to max of "b" *AND* "b" is greater than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the group_by is limits what the agg sees to just what is in each group.

Try this:

```
(
    df
    .group_by('group_col')
    .agg(
        pl.all().max().suffix("max"), 
        pl.all().min().suffix("min")
        )
)
shape: (2, 5)
┌───────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ group_col ┆ bmax ┆ cmax ┆ bmin ┆ cmin │
│ ---       ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str       ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═══════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ g1        ┆ 2    ┆ 5    ┆ 1    ┆ 4    │
│ g2        ┆ 3    ┆ 6    ┆ 3    ┆ 6    │
└───────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

As you can see, for group g1, the cmax is 5 because that's the max in that group's context. So when you get gte as 5 for g1 that's because column b is at its max of 2 for that group.

It seems like what you want is something like:

```
(
    df
    .filter((pl.col('b').max() == pl.col('b')))
    .group_by("group_col")
    .agg( 
        pl.col("c").filter(pl.col("b") >= 1).max().alias("gte"),
    
    )
)
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────┬─────┐
│ group_col ┆ gte │
│ ---       ┆ --- │
│ str       ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪═════╡
│ g2        ┆ 6   │
└───────────┴─────┘
```

but that you want g1 to be returned with a null value. To achieve that you'd have to setup a df with your default rows and then left join the preceding result to that such as:

```
(
    df.select('group_col').unique()
    .join(
        df
        .filter((pl.col('b').max() == pl.col('b')) & (pl.col("b") >= 1))
        .group_by("group_col",maintain_order=True)
        .agg( 
            pl.col("c").max().alias("gte"),
        
        ),
    on='group_col', how='left'
    )
    .sort('group_col')
)
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────┬──────┐
│ group_col ┆ gte  │
│ ---       ┆ ---  │
│ str       ┆ i64  │
╞═══════════╪══════╡
│ g1        ┆ null │
│ g2        ┆ 6    │
└───────────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Lol, I didn't see that, now all makes sense. Thank's bro

Answer (score 1):

The first `.max()` comparison needs to be done at the "column" level, not the "group" level:

```py
(df.with_columns(gte = (pl.col("b") >= 1) & (pl.col("b") == pl.col("b").max()))
   .group_by("group_col")
   .agg(pl.col("c").filter(pl.col("gte")).max())
)
```

```py
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────┬──────┐
│ group_col ┆ c    │
│ ---       ┆ ---  │
│ str       ┆ i64  │
╞═══════════╪══════╡
│ g1        ┆ null │
│ g2        ┆ 6    │
└───────────┴──────┘
```